# Как удалить дубли в массиве со словарями Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, словари

Необходимо удалить дубликаты по ключу значению `name` из массива со словарями.

Пробовал следующее:

```
def remove_duplicates(list):
    seen = set()
    new_list = []
    for item in list:
        t = tuple(item.items())
        if t not in seen:
            seen.add(t)
            new_list.append(item)
    return new_list

input = [{'description': 'second service', 'name': 'service_two', 'value': 'invalid.url:8080'}, \
    {'description': 'First service another description', 'name': 'service_one', 'value': 'invalid.url'}, \
    {'description': 'URL Service', 'name': 'service_one', 'value': 'invalid.url'}, \
    {'description': 'second service', 'name': 'service_two', 'value': 'invalid.url:8080'}]

output = remove_duplicates(input)
print(output)
```

Получаю:

```
[{'description': 'second service', 'name': 'service_two', 'value': 'invalid.url:8080'}, \
{'description': 'First service another description', 'name': 'service_one', 'value': 'invalid.url'}, \
{'description': 'URL Service', 'name': 'service_one', 'value': 'invalid.url'}]
```

Ожидаю получить уникальные словари по элементу `name`(остальные поля не так важны):

```
{'description': 'second service', 'name': 'service_two', 'value': 'invalid.url:8080'}, \
{'description': 'First service another description', 'name': 'service_one', 'value': 'invalid.url'}
```

Comment: list(set(your_list))

Comment: @Эникейщик невнимательно прочитал — точно. [И кстати читайте повнимаетльней...](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10560/%d0%a2%d1%8b-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы хотите сравнивать только "name", но сравниваете абсолютно все. Проверяйте только на повтор "name" и все будет хорошо:

```
def remove_duplicates(lst):
    seen = set()
    new_list = []
    for item in lst:
        item_name = item['name']
        if item_name not in seen:
            seen.add(item_name)
            new_list.append(item)
    return new_list
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно в ваш сет отправлять не все элементы
а только `name`

```
t = tuple(item.name)
```

,
не знаю Pyton но думаю как-то так